# How to make rostopic listen to custom messages

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created my own message type, and have a C++ program generating messages. When I attempt to listen to the messages using `rostopic echo`, I get the following message.

`ERROR: Cannot load message class for [mocap_msgs/LocalMocapFrame]. Are your messages built?`

My messages are built and compiled. Why do I still get this error message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10896/how-to-make-rostopic-listen-to-custom-messages/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-08-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that rostopic is running with the same ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and that the messages are built correctly?  A quick test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('mocap_msgs')
import mocap_msgs.msg

print mocap_msgs.msg.LocalMocapFrame
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-08-15**:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3642

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-15**:
sounds like a bug

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-08-15**:
Excellent. Thank you. Two things: 1) It should be mocap_msgs.msg.LocalMocapFrame 2) The problem was a missing dependency in the manifest. However, rosmake-ing the package showed no errors. Is that a bug?